# Describe the localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, localization

I recently got a rather vague question which stated

Describe the localization $(\mathbb{Z} / 15\mathbb{Z})_{(5)}$ (away from the prime ideal $(5)$).

I know now that this localization is somehow isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{Z} / 5\mathbb{Z}$, but I am not sure how to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Hints.** The localization commutes with the quotients, and $3$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z_{(5)}$.

Comment: You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047698/determining-isomorphism-of-ring-of-fractions-quotients) helpful.